# jQuery-generated gallery of photos in oblique (diagonal) and resizing

Tags: javascript, css, codeigniter, gallery, transform

I am building a webpage with Codeigniter and jQuery with a gallery of images (filenames fetched on the server side) that get displayed in oblique divs. I am using a mix of viewport-relative and percentage dimensions for just about everything. There is no problem at normal aspect ratios, however I would like to keep that sort of layout at all viewport aspect ratios, but this is not the case as the divs shrink too much when the aspect ratio gets too low (I'm fine with the title not being read entirely) or when it gets too high.

This is my code:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="<?php echo asset_url(); ?>js/main.js"></script>
    <div id="main-content">

        <div id="main-topbar">
            T e m p T i t l e
        </div>

        <div id="main-photo">
            <p>Test</p>
        </div>
   </div>
```

these are the relevant css rules:

```
#main-content {
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
}

#main-topbar{
    height: 15%;
    max-height: 15%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    font-family: Georgina, serif;
    text-align: justify;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    line-height: 15vh;
    font-size: 15vh;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    z-index: 100;
}
#main-topbar:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

#main-photo{
    height: 50%;
    max-height: 50%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    border-top: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
}

#main-photo p {
    font-family: "Brush Script MT", cursive;
    line-height: 15vh;
    font-size: 15vh;
    font-style: oblique;
    z-index: 9999;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}

#main-photo .diagonal:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 225%;
    height: 63.33%;
    left: -63%;
    top: 17.67%;
    overflow: hidden;
    -moz-transform: rotate(-30deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-30deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-30deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg);
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
    z-index: -1;
}

#main-photo .diagonal{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 78vh;
    width: 13.3vw;
    bottom: 13.5vh;
    float: left;
    -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(30deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
    transform: rotate(30deg);
    margin-left: 2vw;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

and this is the javascript:

```
$(function() {

$.ajax({ url: './index.php/main/getSlides/',
    success: function(output) {
        if (output && output != '') {
            var parsed_output = JSON.parse(output);
            var photos = 6;
            for (var i = 0; i < photos; i++) {
                $("#main-photo").append('<span id="bg-'+i+'" class="diagonal"></span>');
            }
            var i = 0;
            $(".diagonal").each(function(){
                document.styleSheets[0].addRule('#bg-'+i+':before', 'background-image: url("../../assets/main photos/'+parsed_output[i]+'");');
                document.styleSheets[0].addRule('#bg-'+i+':before', 'background-size: cover;');
                document.styleSheets[0].addRule('#bg-'+i+':before', 'background-position: center;');
                i++;
            });
        }
    }
});
});
```

I tried forcing the aspect ratio of the oblique divs when the aspect ratio of the viewport causes these issues, using this event handler:

```
$(window).on('resize orientationChange', function(event) {
    var ratio = 4.65;
    var low = 3.44;
    var high = 6;
    var width = $("#main-photo").width();
    var height = $("#main-photo").height();
    var curr_ratio = width / (height+0.001);
    if (curr_ratio < low) {
        var curr_width = parseInt($(".diagonal").height() / low);
        $(".diagonal").removeClass("long11").addClass("short11");
        $(".diagonal.short11").css("width", curr_width.toString()+'px');
    } else if (curr_ratio > high) {
        var curr_height = parseInt($(".diagonal").width() * high);
        $(".diagonal").removeClass("short11").addClass("long11");
        $(".diagonal.long11").css("height", curr_height.toString()+"px");
    } else {
        $(".diagonal.short11").css("width", "13.3vw");
        $(".diagonal.long11").css("height", "78vh");
        $(".diagonal").removeClass("short11 long11");
    }
});
```

which makes things slightly better when aspect ratios are not too extreme, but after a while some divs go below the container div if the aspect ratio is extremely low, and all of them do if it is too high.

The set of "appearences" can be seen in [this album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alYkQ.jpg) (in order: correct behaviour, low aspect ratio without resize listener, low aspect ratio with resize listener, high aspect ratio without listener, high aspect ratio with listener)

What I would like is keeping the images displayed as if they were separated by diagonal lines (so the example with normal aspect ratio) at all times, I would be fine with not displaying some images if the width is too low, or clipping/cropping them, but how do I do that?

please note that the images are loaded with ajax from a PHP controller because in the future I want to be able to randomize the photos, add animations and such, so I cannot set static background images.